# How to clone an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, mvvm

This is for a MVVM based WPF project:

I am using an `ExpandoObject` in a view model for a dialog, which works very nicely since it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I can bind to properties of the object directly in XAML.

However, to account for the user manipuating data but then hitting cancel I need to make a copy of the `ExpandoObject` to restore the original content.

In the dialog no properties are added to the object.

How can I clone it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a remaining believer in static typing, eugh...

That being said, it looks like `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
dynamic foo1d = new ExpandoObject();
foo1d.a = "test";

dynamic foo2d = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var kvp in (IDictionary<string, object>)foo1d)
{
    ((IDictionary<string, object>)foo2d).Add(kvp);
}

Debug.Assert(foo1d.a == foo2d.a);
```

or in VB:

```
Dim foo1d As Object = New ExpandoObject
Dim foo2d As Object = New ExpandoObject
foo1d.a = "foo"

Dim cloneDictionary = CType(foo2d, IDictionary(Of String, Object))
For Each line In CType(foo1d, IDictionary(Of String, Object))
    cloneDictionary.Add(line.Key, line.Value)
Next
```

I will note that this is only a shallow clone.  You would have to do further work do clone referenced objects.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I was hoping for a simpler solution but it seems there isn't one.

Comment: Can anyone share in VB.net?  The converters are having a hard time with this code from C# to VB.net.

Comment: @JoshYates1980, added.

Answer (score 15):

Shallow copy:

```
static ExpandoObject ShallowCopy(ExpandoObject original)
{
    var clone = new ExpandoObject();

    var _original = (IDictionary<string, object>)original;
    var _clone = (IDictionary<string, object>)clone;

    foreach (var kvp in _original)
        _clone.Add(kvp);

    return clone;
}
```

Deep copy:

```
static ExpandoObject DeepCopy(ExpandoObject original)
{
    var clone = new ExpandoObject();

    var _original = (IDictionary<string, object>)original;
    var _clone = (IDictionary<string, object>)clone;

    foreach (var kvp in _original)
        _clone.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value is ExpandoObject ? DeepCopy((ExpandoObject)kvp.Value) : kvp.Value);

    return clone;
}
```

Comment: For the deep copy what if the `kvp.Value` in the `ExpandoObject` is a `IList<>` item? It looks like it'll do a shallow copy for those instead of a deep copy by just assigning the `kvp.Value` to `kvp,Key` in the `_clone`.

Answer (score -2):

```
var ExpandoObjs = GetDynamicList();
//clone
var clonedExpandos = ExpandoObjs.Cast<dynamic>().Select(x => x).ToList();
//modify and sort
var transformedExpandos = ExpandoObjs.Cast<dynamic>().Select(x =>
{
    x.url= x.url + " some more stuff";
    return x;
}).OrderBy(x => x.order).ToList();
```

as long as url is a property of the dynamic object, this will work.

It's useful if you're consuming a service call that doesn't have concrete types and you want to modify/sort the result.